# Joining translate table, keeping order form indexes in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I use this SQL to grab some indexes:

```
select follow 
from unigram 
where alternativeSpelling like 'test' 
order by freq desc 
limit 10;
```

I then convert them to words using this SQL, one by one:

```
select word 
from wordIdxTranslate 
where word_idx = <one of the indexes from above>
```

How do I combine these to a single query, whil epreserving the ranking order from the first query ("freq")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but this should do it:

```
SELECT word 
FROM unigram, wordIdxTranslate
WHERE 
    unigram.follow=wordIdxTranslate.word_idx
    AND
    unigram.follow IN (SELECT T1.follow 
                       FROM unigram AS T1 
                       WHERE T1.alternativeSpelling LIKE 'test' 
                       ORDER BY T1.freq DESC 
                       LIMIT 10)
ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Comment: Downvote ain't from me. The answer seems to work as advertised, so I'm happy as a clam.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to combine the queries with a `join`, like:

```
select  word 
from    (
        select  follow 
        ,       freq
        from    unigram 
        where   alternativeSpelling like 'test' 
        order by 
                freq desc 
        limit 10
        ) uni
join    wordIdxTranslate  wit
on      wit.word_idx = uni.follow
order by
        uni.freq desc
```